# How can I fix this Node.js login page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

```
I'm breaking my head with a Node js with mysql database and trying to make a simple login.

I am getting :Cannot POST /login

<body class="hero-image">

<div id="container">
    <div id="tabs">

       <p id="lt" class="tabs">Log in</p>
        <p id="rt" class="tabs" onclick="location.href = './register';">Register</p>

        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="cont">
        <div id="loginBox" class="comm">
            <h3>Sign in</h3>
            <form action="login" method="POST">
                <input id="username" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                <input id="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        const form = document.getElementById('login')
        form.addEventListener('submit', login)

        async function login(event) {
            alert('Success')
            event.preventDefault()
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value
            
            
            
            const result = await fetch('/api/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username,
                    password
                })
            }).then((res) => res.json())

            if (result.status === 'ok') {
                // everythign went fine
                console.log('Got the token: ', result.data)
                localStorage.setItem('token', result.data)
                alert('Success')
            } else {
                if (result.status === 'Not Found') {
                    alert("Incorrect Username and/or Password!");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please enter Username and Password!");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And this node js script:
```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var express = require('express');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var path = require('path')
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
    
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'sportacus3',
        database : 'nodelogin'
    });
    
    var app = express();
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'secret',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));
    
    
    app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");
    });
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/landing-page.html");
    });
    
    app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/register.html");
    });
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    app.get('/', function(request, response) {
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'));
    });
    
    
    app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
        var dialog = require('dialog');
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        if (!username) {
            return res.json({ status: 'Not Found', data: 'Invalid username/password' });
        }
        if (username && password) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    return res.json({ status: 'ok', data: username });
                } else {
                    return res.json({ status: 'Not Found', data: 'Incorrect Username and/or Password!' });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    
    app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
        if (request.session.loggedin) {
            response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.username + '!');
            response.end();
        } else {
            //response.send('Please login to view this page!');
            alert('Please login to view this page!');
        }
        
    });
    
    app.listen(3000);
```
I'd really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, bro!

I tried to make an effort to unscramble the backend code but for now you're posting to the "/api/login" and your html form action is targeting "login".

To make the right call to the post method, change your html to the following action:

```
 <form action="/api/login" method="POST">
```

So it matches the right call you're trying to do, which is:

```
app.post("/api/login", async(req, res) => {...});
```

Comment: I sincerely tried to make it more comprehensible, but it was 3 am when I posted it, and in the editor it seemed fine :(

Answer (score -2):

You can do the method that changes the correct form action as pointed out by @Rafael Nicola, or you can simply change the app.post to /login since you are working on localhost